# How to check whether a command such as curl completed without error?

Tags: curl, http, error-handling

I am using curl to upload a file to a server via an HTTP post.

```
curl -X POST -d@myfile.txt server-URL
```

When I manually execute this command on the command line, I get a response from the server like `"Upload successful"`. However, how if I want to execute this curl command via a script, how can I find out if my POST request was successful?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The simplest way is to store the response and compare it:

```
$ response=$(curl -X POST -d@myfile.txt server-URL);
$ if [ "Upload successful" == "${response}" ]; then … fi;
```

I haven't tested that. The syntax might be off, but that's the idea. I'm sure there are more sophisticated ways of doing it such as checking curl's exit code or something.

#### update

`curl` returns quite a few exit codes. I'm guessing a failed post might result in `55 Failed sending network data.` So you could probably just make sure the exit code was zero by comparing to `$?` (`Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.`):

```
$ curl -X POST -d@myfile.txt server-URL;
$ if [ 0 -eq $? ]; then … fi;
```

Or if your command is relatively short and you want to do something when it fails, you could rely on the exit code as the condition in a conditional statement:

```
$ if curl --fail -X POST -d@myfile.txt server-URL; then
    # …(success)
else
    # …(failure)
fi;
```

I think this format [is often preferred](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd.3B_.28.28_.21_.24.3F_.29.29_.7C.7C_die), but personally I find it less readable.

Answer (score 34):

You might be able to use `curl's --fail` option, though you should test it once first.

```
man curl
```

> -f, --fail
>                 (HTTP)  Fail  silently (no output at all) on server errors. This
>                 is mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal  with
>                 failed  attempts.  In  normal cases when an HTTP server fails to
>                 deliver a document, it  returns  an  HTML  document  stating  so
>                 (which  often  also describes why and more). This flag will pre‐
>                 vent curl from outputting that and return error 22.
>
> ```
>           This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where  non-
>           successful  response  codes  will  slip through, especially when
>           authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).
> ```

In this way you could just do:

```
args="-X POST -d@myfile.txt server-URL"
curl -f $args && echo "SUCCESS!" ||
    echo "OH NO!"
```

Comment: This is probably the best practice in a scripting setting. For cURL exit codes see here: https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/returns