# Ignore very specific error message in bash

Tags: bash

`script.sh:`

```
#!/bin/bash
my-bin-file-i-run

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    exit 0
else
    if [[ >&2 == *"name_to_handle_at"* ]]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    echo >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

I'd like to run my command and if it throws an error which the message includes "name_to_handle_at" it will handle it like the script had no errors, all other errors should be shown as usual. Can't really get it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a command such as curl completed without error?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124918/how-to-check-whether-a-command-such-as-curl-completed-without-error)

Comment: Some sort of [exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934392) for bash?

Comment: Something like `if out=$(my-bin-file-i-run 2>&1); then ... elif [[ $out == .... ]] ...`

Comment: Or even closer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477820/how-to-pipe-the-stdout-of-a-command-depending-on-the-result-of-the-exit-code/477934#477934

Comment: to capture only stderr in a variable, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130375/bash-script-store-stderr-in-a-variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is faulty as you can't just compare the standard error of some previously executed command with `==` like that.

One suggestion is to save the error stream to a file and then parse that:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if ! my-bin-file-i-run 2>error.log; then
    if ! grep -q -F 'name_to_handle_at' error.log; then
       echo 'some error message' >&2
       exit 1
    fi
fi
```

This would run the command and redirect the standard error stream to a file called `error.log`.  If the command terminates with an error, `grep` is used to look for the string `name_to_handle_at` in the log file.  If that can't be found, an error message is printed and the script terminates with a non-zero exit status.

In any other case, the script terminates with a zero exit status.

If you want the `error.log` file to be removed when your script terminates, you may do so explicitly with `rm error.log` in the appropriate places, or with an `EXIT` trap:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap 'rm -f error.log' EXIT

if ! my-bin-file-i-run 2>error.log; then
    if ! grep -q -F 'name_to_handle_at' error.log; then
       echo 'some error message' >&2
       exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Ah, interesting! Is there a way to do this with variables instead of error files by any chance?

Comment: @KarlMorrison Capturing the output from a program is definitely possible with a command substitution, but since we don't know if this output may contain megabytes of data, or just a few lines of text, it may be safer to just send the data to a temporary file.  The code also becomes a fair bit uglier (IMHO).

Comment: Your `trap` at the top changed my mind, thanks!

Comment: @KarlMorrison There's also nothing stopping you from using `mktemp` to create the name of the error log file (`errlog=$(mktemp)`, then `... 2>"$errlog"` etc.)  This would likely create the file under `/tmp` which _may_ be a memory mounted filesystem (no writes to disk).

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the stderr of your program to grep and use the (**bash-specific**) `PIPESTATUS` variable to distinguish between the 4 combinations of command succeeded / failed and command printed / did not print that error message:

```
{ your_command 2>&1 >&3 | grep your_error_message >/dev/null; } 3>&1
case ${PIPESTATUS[*]} in
0*) ;; # the command succeeded
*0) ;; # the command failed but printed the error message
esac
```

Example:

```
# usage wrapper pattern cmd args ...
wrapper(){
    msg=$1; shift
    { "$@" 2>&1 >&3 | grep "$msg" >/dev/null; } 3>&1
    case ${PIPESTATUS[*]} in
    0*|*0) return 0;;
    *) return "${PIPESTATUS[0]}";;
    esac
}

# usage test_cmd status error_message
test_cmd(){ status=$1; shift; echo >&2 "$@"; return "$status"; }

$ wrapper foo test_cmd 13 foo; echo $?
0
$ wrapper foo test_cmd 13 bar; echo $?
13
```

Notes:

Do not replace the `grep >/dev/null` with `grep -q`; that will cause grep to exit at the first match and cause your command to be SIGPIPEd.

You can however put a `... | tee /dev/stderr | ...` between your command and the grep; that will cause error messages to be both passed to grep and printed to stderr.

Many subpar programs (especially python scripts) write error messages to stdout instead of stderr; if that's the case you can simply use

```
your_command 2>&1 | ...
```

instead of all that `{ 2>&1 >&3 | ... } >&3` fd juggling.