# What's a clean way to run a specific command C for each line L of a given file F and then move every L where C(L) ran unsuccesfully?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, zsh

Say that

```
https://example.nosuchtld
https://example.net
https://example.org
https://example.willfail
```

is the content of `urls.txt`. I want to run `<command> <url>` for every URL/line of `urls.txt` —where `<command>` is, let's say, `curl`; so,

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -n1 curl
```

or

```
<urls.txt xargs -n1 curl
```

for instance. I want every URL/line which was unsuccessfully `curl`ed (so, the first and last ones) to

1. be removed from `urls.txt`; and
2. be appended to another file —let's say `nope.txt`— to be created if it doesn't already exist

leaving `urls.txt` as

```
https://example.net
https://example.org
```

and `nope.txt` as

```
https://example.nosuchtld
https://example.willfail
```

I know that the exit status of every command run by the shell is made available via the variable `$?`, that `0` represents successful execution of a command, and that all other integers represent failure. I'm unsure, though, of how to construct a composite command that incorporates this, deletes lines from the file being read from, and appends 'em to a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With zsh, you could do:

```
while IFS= read -ru3 url; do
  curl -- $url
  print -ru $(( $? ? 4 : 5 )) -- $url
done 3< urls 4> bad 5> good
```

That way, the `bad` and `good` files are opened only once and only if `urls` itself can be opened for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash`, you can loop for the urls and test the `curl` command, `--fail` option of `curl` seems to be good for use inside scripts, see:
[How to check whether a command such as curl completed without error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124918/how-to-check-whether-a-command-such-as-curl-completed-without-error)

So it could be like this:

```
while read -r url; do
    curl -f "$url" && outputfile='success.txt' || outputfile='nope.txt'
    printf "%s\n" "$url" >> "$outputfile"
done < urls.txt
```

and overwrite your file with the successful urls.

```
mv success.txt urls.txt
```

---

Or use `mapfile` to put the lines into an array:

```
mapfile -t urls < urls.txt

for url in "${urls[@]}"; do
    curl -f "$url" && outputfile='success.txt' || outputfile='nope.txt'
    printf "%s\n" "$url" >> "$outputfile"
done
```

---

Note that urls have no spaces. If you need to execute a command where the argument would be a whole line, with any characters, then this post is useful on how to read every line: [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line)

Comment: Thanks! I had in mind leveraging the exit status because, despite having happened to select `curl` as an example to concertize my question, I'm really looking to understand a solution or solutions that'd be likely to work with any command including those that lack a `--fail` option. Consider, for instance, the command line app [nb](https://xwmx.github.io/nb/): it has no such flag. What could be done, then, when processing a URL file with it? Thoughts?

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Okay 

Comment:  I see, I see… the success exit status is being implicitly checked for at the `&&` logical operator, verdad?